# How to Allow user to right click button or linkbutton to open in new tab

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using asp.net server controls in my application. If I click on any control it opens in same tab and works fine. **But I want that when user right clicks the button or any other control it should open in new tab**. Is there any way we can right click on any button or link button can be used. Or **Hyperlink is the only way to do this**.

Comment: can't you just subscribe to right button click from javascript (on the client) and open in a new window ?

Comment: You can use to open in newtab on button click

 link.Target = "_blank";

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/630793/Context-Menu-on-Right-Click-in-Webpage

Comment: Show us the code with what you want to do ??

Comment: Was my answer helpful with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the contexmenu override to achieve this, something like (haven't tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.addEventListener) {
        document.addEventListener('contextmenu', function(e) {
            // Your code to open link here
            e.preventDefault();
        }, false);
    } else {
        document.attachEvent('oncontextmenu', function() {
            window.event.returnValue = false;
        });
    }
</script>
```

If you want to do it in jQuery, check this link:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-modify-right-click-menu/